# Webservice on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, web-services, webforms

I have a webservice and a webform. A button invokes the webservice which reads a given process name from pid. This works fine in VS2008 but when I publish my project I dont get the name? How can I configure IIS to allow me to do so? or is there an alternative way i.e. wcf or wwf?

Edit:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

[WebMethod]
        public string GetProcessName()
        {
            Process Process = Process.GetProcessById(1428);
            string ProcessTitle = Process.MainWindowTitle;
            return ProcessTitle;
        }
```

I used tasklist.exe /v to get the pid of a process which has a window title.

Comment: See for any exception in the windows events. There might be an issue of authorisation. When you run the code from VS, its the user on the OS that invokes. But on IIS the user will be ASPNET. ASPNET might not be authorised to run the particular code. In such a code, you might get the exception in the security or application events.

Answer (score 0):

Given your code:

- how do you know there's a process with PID = 1428 ??
- what happens if that process doesn't exist?

If you check out this line of code:

```
Process process = Process.GetProcessById(1428);
```

will return `NULL`, and then you grab the `.MainWindowTitle` from...... NULL..... that's **guaranteed** to cause an exception.....

```
using System.Diagnostics;

[WebMethod]
public string GetProcessName()
{
   string processTitle = string.Empty;

   Process process = Process.GetProcessById(1428);

   if(process != null)
   {     
      processTitle = process.MainWindowTitle;
   }

   return processTitle;
}
```

And even so - again: how do you know a process with ID = 1428 exists??

Comment: I used tasklist.exe /v to get the pid of a process which has a window title. I mentioned this under the code. 1428 was my chrome browser (google.com) so I am sure it exits :p

Answer (score 0):

I can't believe that when I deployed my project to Abyss web server it works like a charm.
Thanks all anyways.